# MDX Query Error when using Order clause - An expression was expected for the function argument and no expression was detected

Tags: mdx

i have this MDX query and i am trying to add Order clause in this query. The error i'm getting is:  An expression was expected for the function argument and no expression was detected.

Please suggest how to add order clause in this query.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[DateMax] AS
    DateAdd('s', -1, DateAdd('h', 1, [TIME].[TIME].LastChild.PrevMember.Member_VALUE))

SELECT
non empty { [Measures].[DURATION], 
    [Measures].[SELL], 
    [Measures].[BUY], 
    [Measures].[PROFIT], 
    [Measures].[PROFIT PERCENTAGE]}  on columns,
non empty (                         
    ([CUSTOMERS].[CUSTOMER].[CUSTOMER])
  -- ORDER([CUSTOMERS].[CUSTOMER].[CUSTOMER], ASC)
  ) on rows
FROM [PROFIT]
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a parameter of `[Order]` statement. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms145587.aspx) is the docs

```
ORDER([CUSTOMERS].[CUSTOMER].[CUSTOMER], [Measures].[SELL], ASC)
```

will probably solve your problem. You need a Numeric or a String expression to order by: in my example you will order by SELL measure value.